# How Openshift DIY cartridge kicks off processes?

Tags: playframework-2.0, openshift

Does DIY cartridge support running 2 processes in each gear? If I have 2 gears running, does it mean it will have 4 processes running at the same time?

> start

```
chmod +x ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}run/start

APP_COMMAND_1="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}run/start $PLAY_PARAMS "\
"-Dhttp.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} "\
"-Dhttp.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} "\
"-Dlogger.resource=${LOGGER_RESOURCE} "\
"-Dconfig.resource=application-prod.conf"

echo $APP_COMMAND_1 &>> $LOG_FILE
nohup bash -c "${APP_COMMAND_1} &>> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1" &> /dev/null &

APP_COMMAND_2="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}run/start $PLAY_PARAMS "\
"-Dhttp.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} "\
"-Dhttp.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} "\
"-Dlogger.resource=${LOGGER_RESOURCE} "\
"-Dconfig.resource=application-prod.conf "\
"-Dapplication.global=Scheduler"

echo $APP_COMMAND_2 &>> $LOG_FILE
nohup bash -c "${APP_COMMAND_2} &>> ${LOG_FILE} 2>&1" &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: You'll probably get a bind exception failure on the second process since you can't start 2 listeners on the same port.  Also, not sure what you mean with 2 DIY gears as that would constitute 2 different applications (DIY is not scalable at this time).

Comment: I was looking for a way to implement like Heroku "web" & "worker". Do you have any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the web / worker model on Openshift then you'll need to use something like Redis. And it just so happens we have a downloadable Redis cart https://www.openshift.com/blogs/enabling-redis-for-your-app.